# Is it possible to disable dojo spider chart animation?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, dojo, web-crawler

If I convert the given html to pdf with wkhtmltopdf the chart data will not show because it is rendered when the animation is not yet complete.

Does anyone know of a way to disable the animation?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
    <script>
        dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
            var chart = new dojox.charting.Chart("chart");
            chart.addPlot("default", { type: "Spider", });
            chart.addSeries("China", {data: {"GDP": 2, "area": 6, "population": 2000, "inflation": 15, "growth": 12}}, { fill: "blue" });
            chart.addSeries("USA", {data: {"GDP": 3, "area": 20, "population": 1500, "inflation": 10, "growth": 3}}, { fill: "green" });
            chart.addSeries("Canada", {data: {"GDP": 1, "area": 18, "population": 300, "inflation": 3, "growth": 15}}, { fill: "purple" });
            chart.render();    
        });      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Spider plot does not support a duration setting for its animations (no idea why), but you can see a modified version of the JS file here that should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/zvyhW/

Also I would encourage you to file a bug ticket here: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org as an enhancement request for your problem

Comment: You'd better subclass the existing Spider class rather than overriding its definition. It allows you to replace only the methods that need to be replaced. You easily can end-up with a custom spider where the anim duration is configurable... see this fork from your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/yjjB9/

Answer (score 2):

Two years after the last answer, you now have a better option.

Example:

```
new Chart(t.spiderNode)
      .addPlot("default", {
        type: Spider,
        animate: false
      });
```

PS: This should work since dojo 1.7.